# All my code signing settings in Xcode got changed, Provisioning profile no longer works

Tags: nativescript

I have been working to get everything configured between apple, firebase, xcode, and nativescript.  And everything finally was working great.  And I continued developing, I added the android platform next, and then an icon and a splash screen in sidekick.

And lo and behold, it blew out all of my precious XCode settings that I agonized for days over. I don't know why, and I don't know which action did it unless I revert back. It changed to "automatically" signing everything.  So I removed that and put the settings back, and now my provisioning profile won't work.

XCode says it lacks the keychain abilities, but my app doesn't use the keychain, and it's not enabled.  This profile worked three hours ago.  What did I do wrong here?

Comment: May be it's unable to find the right certificate from your Mac Keychain for given provisional profile. Where have you configured the provisional & certificate, build.xcconfig?

Comment: Go to build settings and search for "sign", there are more variables you can change which are not shown under "signing & Capabilities" tab.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to delete the keyring entries from the entitlements file.